# Soft Back button for Android Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

As per the design rule is it really a good idea to introduce a back button for Activity in Android?

I believe every device, now a days, or running Android OS has a hardware back button.

What is your suggestion on implementing software back button?

How can I enable it, if at all hardware back button support is not present?

Comment: I still haven't seen any android device without Back button have seen ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana Sorry if I am not clear i have just updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//enable soft back button
    ActionBar ab =getSupportActionBar(); 
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }

//handle click event
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
if(id==android.R.id.home){
onBackPressed();
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

There are new way for going back is home button of Toolbar.you can enable home button in your toolbar(actionbar) for go to back.

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1):

Lollipop introduced a new software back button in the Action Bar.  You should read all docs about [Material design](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html%23StatusBar)

To navigate back from an activity, just call

```
finish()
```

Read some info on the back stack, as this is key to navigate using both activities and fragments